# Syntax Errors in Code Renderer?

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418970/java-reduceleft-signature-lower-bounded-type-arguments) about a syntactic impossibility in Java, I had to write a chunk of code that purposely contained a syntax error. After submitting the question, I was reasonably surprised because the code renderer on Stack Overflow actually *showed me the syntax error*, as seen in this snapshot (in case it doesn't work for you):

[image]

Am I being tricked by an optical illusion or is this a new feature?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The syntax highlighter didn't pick up that you wanted Java highlighting. Instead, it seems to be interpreted as HTML (probably because it begins with a `<`). HTML attributes are set to be colored red, which is why you are seeing the "Java Error". Just use the following and it should work:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->

    <B super A> B reduceLeft(BiFunction<? super B, ? super A, ? extends B> mapper)
```

Which produces:

```java
<B super A> B reduceLeft(BiFunction<? super B, ? super A, ? extends B> mapper)
```

That way, you are explicitly stating that the code should be highlighted as Java.

Comment: *Why did you have to ruin this awesome coincidence?*

Comment: Oh well. It is quite an odd coincidence though. :)